# AngularJS and Bootstrap not rendering properly after deployment in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, iis

I am experiencing a weird behavior on my project. The website is using `ASP.NET MVC 5`, `Bootstrap 3.2.0`, `AngularJS 1.2.18`.

In my **development machine**, I tested my website on the following browsers:

- Firefox 30 (*working properly*)
- Internet Explorer 9 (*working properly*)
- Internet Explorer 11 (*working properly*)

But when I deploy it on the different server which runs `IIS 7.5`, only Firefox renders properly:

- Firefox 30 (*working properly*)
- Internet Explorer 9 (*bootstrap not working and angularjs not binding*)
- Internet Explorer 11 (*bootstrap not working and angularjs not binding*)

Any idea why it only works on my development machine? Does it have any connection with the configuration on IIS? If this question needs improvement, please let me know the important detail that needs to be included.

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the files in the VS:

[image]

Full code in `BundleConfig.cs`

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angularjs").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/angular.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/normalizeBundle").Include(
                  "~/Content/normalize.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapBundle").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/cerulean-bootstrap-theme.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
```

and on `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - IODashboard</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/normalizeBundle")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapBundle")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    @* more lines here *@

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the scripts included in the final HTML source? Are the scripts "included" to the Visual Studio solution?

Comment: @RowanFreeman all are included because it renders properly on firefox on both environment: developemtn and on IIS. I was wondering if there is special configuration on IIS 7.5 for MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

should be

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

The `Scripts` tag is case sensitive.